# How to retrieve NuGet package with all dependencies to local folder?

Tags: nuget

In our company, we have an on-premise NuGet server. Now I'd like to add the package [Fluent Assertions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions). I can easily get it by executing the following command:

`nuget install FluentAssertions -OutputDirectory C:\temp\NuGet`

But in **C:\temp\NuGet**, I only find **FluentAssertions**, but not its dependencies.

Is there any one-liner that download's them as well into **C:\temp\NuGet**? Or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependencies are framework-specific. You'll have to chose one framework you want the depencies for using the appropriate option

[Nuget-Cli-Reference (install)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install)

Comment: Great, thank you! For the sake of completeness: my final call is `nuget install FluentAssertions -OutputDirectory C:\temp\NuGet -Framework .NETFramework4.5`